# Simulate javascript serialization in python tests

Tags: python, unit-testing, serialization, django-forms

I have a web-service that allows the user to fill in a form, click a button, and my app checks whether it is possible to login to another server using data from the form.

Now I want to write a test for that - make sure that when I pass correct data my function is able to connect to the server, and that it returns the right message if it can't.

What normally happens is that, after the button is clicked, the following js function is run:

```
function someFunction(person_id) {
    Dajaxice.someAjaxFunction(someCallback, {
        'person_id': person_id,
        'credentials_form': $("#some_form").serialize(true)
    });
    loading.show_loader();
}
```

Later on, the ajax function calls a view function, which does the following:

```
def some_python_function(person_id, credentials_form):
    credentials, created = SomeCredentials.objects.get_or_create(person=person_id)
    some_cred_form= SomeCredentialsForm(deserialize_form(credentials_form), instance=credentials)
    if some_cred_form.is_valid():
        try:
            (...some_words_and_things_here...)
```

Now, my problem is that while writing the test I don't call the js function, I just want to send the form to some_python_function. However, I can't do it directly:

```
    form_data = {'data_1': data_1, "data_2": data_2, 'data_3': data_3}
    form = SomeCredentialsForm(data=form_data)
    self.assertEqual(some_python_function(person_id, form), (...))
```

Obviously, this doesn't work: since some_cred_form.is_valid() == False, the relevant part of the code is not being checked.
I need to somehow do to my form whatever the js function does. But how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery serialize method returns just a query string. You could try to create a similar string and pass it to the function:

```
form_data = 'data_1={}&data_2={}&data_3={}'.format(data_1, data_2, data_3)
self.assertEqual(some_python_function(person_id, form_data), (...))
```

Comment: I checked it myself  in debug mode in PyCharm and it seems that it also adds some kind of a token(?). I guess I don't have to worry about that?

Comment: That's csrf token. It is present in a form as a hidden input. You don't need to worry about it in tests: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/csrf/#testing. By the way, why your view don't take a request as a first argument?

Comment: Well the request is an argument in the ajax function but not required otherwise from what I can tell - it only returns a message to the callback. Perhaps I wrongly used the word "view", as there aren't any views rendered, just a JSON response with a message that afterwards is converted to a success or error message. Anyway, thanks for help, I'll try it soon and accept if it works!

Comment: ups sorry, completely forgot about that! Accepted :)